# Impala built-in function: unix_timestamp function is not accurate enough

Tags: impala, built-in

I am using the following impala query to extract data from my_table:

```
select id, timestamp, unix_timestamp(timestamp) as ts from my_table
```

The output is:

```
        id          timestamp               ts
-------------------------------------------------------
    0   A       2016-08-21 16:18:34.336     1471796314
    1   A       2016-08-21 16:18:34.517     1471796314
    2   A       2016-08-21 16:18:34.677     1471796314
    3   B       2016-08-14 00:20:00.641     1471134000
    4   B       2016-08-14 00:20:00.697     1471134000
    5   B       2016-08-14 00:20:00.720     1471134000
    6   B       2016-08-14 00:20:00.750     1471134000
```

---

The converted `ts` field becomes all the same because the original timestamp difference is very small. Is there a way (a function) which can make `ts` using higher digits (accuracy)? I need every `ts` to be different if the original timestamp is different. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With a **recent** version of Impala *[caveat below]*, you should be able to extract the milliseconds and reconstruct a more precise timestamp.
*Caveat - the [Cloudera documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html) states that the `millisecond()` function is available in CDH 5.7.0 which is clearly not the case.*

```
SELECT Unix_Timestamp(timestamp)*1000 +Millisecond(timestamp) AS ts FROM wtf
```

By the way, be very careful about Time Zones. Impala assumes that all timestamps are provided as UTC, so if your data comes from multiple Data Centers -- or from a Data Center that applies DST -- your precision loss is a matter of *hours*, not of milliseconds...